# Solving set of Boundary Value Problems

Tags: python, numpy, ode, differential-equations, boundary

I am trying to solve a set of boundary value problems given by 4 differential equations. I am using bvp_solver in python, and I am getting errors which state 'invalid value encountered in division'. I am assuming this means I am dividing by NaN or 0 at some point, but I am unsure where.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
alpha = 1
zeta = 1
C_k = 1
sigma = 1
Q = 30
U_0 = 0.1
gamma = 5/3
theta = 3
m = 1.5
def fun(x, y):
    U, dU, B, dB, T, dT, M, dM = y;
    d2U = -2*U_0*Q**2*(1/np.cosh(Q*x))**2*np.tanh(Q*x)-((alpha)/(C_k*sigma))*dB;   
    d2B = -(1/(C_k*zeta))*dU;
    d2T = (1/gamma - 1)*(sigma*dU**2 + zeta*alpha*dB**2);
    d2M = -(dM/T)*dT + (dM/T)*theta*(m+1) - (alpha/T)*B*dB
    return dU, d2U, dB, d2B, dT, d2T, dM, d2M 

def bc(ya, yb):

    return ya[0]+U_0*np.tanh(Q*0.5), yb[0]-U_0*np.tanh(Q*0.5), ya[2]-0, yb[2]-0, ya[4] - 1, yb[4] - 4, ya[6], yb[6] - 1

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 500)
y = np.zeros((8, x.size))


sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
```

If I remove the last two equations for M and dM, then the solution works fine. I have had trouble in the past understanding the return arrays of bvp_solver, but I am confident I understand that now. But I continue to get errors each time I add more equations. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this will fail in the first step. You initialize everything to zero, and then in the derivatives function, you divide by `T`, which is zero from the initialization.

- Find a more realistic initialization of `T`, for instance

  ```
  x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 15)
  y = np.zeros((8, x.size))
  y[4] = 2.5+3*x
  y[5] = 3+0*x
  ```

  or
- desingularize the division, which usually is done similar to

  ```
  d2M = (-dM*dT + dM*theta*(m+1) - alpha*B*dB) * T/(1e-12+T*T)
  ```

It makes always sense to print after `sol = solve_bvp(...)` the error message `print(sol.message)`. Now that there are more than a few components, I changed the construction of the output tableau to the systematic

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2.5*4))
for k in range(4):
    v,c = ['U','B','T','M'][k],['-+b','-*r','-xg','-om'][k];
    plt.subplot(4,2,2*k+1); plt.plot(sol.x,sol.y[2*k  ],c, ms=2); plt.grid(); plt.legend(["$%c$"%v]);
    plt.subplot(4,2,2*k+2); plt.plot(sol.x,sol.y[2*k+1],c, ms=2); plt.grid(); plt.legend(["$%c'$"%v]);
plt.tight_layout(); plt.savefig("/tmp/bvp3.png"); plt.show(); plt.close()
```

Comment: I have been solving these equations, but however I have noticed that my solution for M and dM is changing when I change how many grid points I have in x that I pass to bvp_solve. It is not clear to me if I am converging to the true solution or what exactly is happening.

Comment: If the solver returns "successful", then it is highly likely close to a solution. Note that a BVP that is non-linear in any of its parts can have several solutions. The initial guess influences which of them is reached.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. How do I output the successful message from my code?

Comment: You  have the logical flag `sol.success` that you can use to stop further processing in the case of a failure, and the text message `sol.message` that you can put in a print statement.